# Strange NullPointerException crash after updating to new Android Google Maps API v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have recently been nudged to update my app to use google maps API v2. (Google finally discontinued granting API keys for v1 for good.) I have implemented the new api to work the same as my app worked before to my satisfaction. Except, I noticed a weird bug that happens.

When I go to my activity that uses the SupportMapFragment, press back to go to the previous activity, and then go forward to the SupportMapFragment activity again, it will randomly crash... Sometimes quickly, and sometimes it takes a minute. The only thing that has changed is that I'm using the new API and thus refactored code to use the new API.

```
04-25 08:00:24.415: W/dalvikvm(12746): threadid=28: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40b9f930)
04-25 08:00:24.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12746): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1711
04-25 08:00:24.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12746): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 08:00:24.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12746):    at libcore.net.http.RequestHeaders.addCookies(RequestHeaders.java:285)
04-25 08:00:24.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12746):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.prepareRawRequestHeaders(HttpEngine.java:724)
04-25 08:00:24.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12746):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:217)
04-25 08:00:24.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12746):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
04-25 08:00:24.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12746):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:495)
04-25 08:00:24.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12746):    at maps.z.bk.run(Unknown Source)
04-25 08:00:24.475: W/ActivityManager(517):   Force finishing activity com.___.___/com.___.___.activities.ActivityWithMap
04-25 08:00:24.625: D/overlay(158): Unset pipe=VG0 dpy=0; Unset pipe=VG1 dpy=0; Unset pipe=RGB1 dpy=0; 
04-25 08:00:37.398: I/Process(12746): Sending signal. PID: 12746 SIG: 9
04-25 08:00:37.418: I/ActivityManager(517): Process com.___.___ (pid 12746) has died.
04-25 08:00:37.418: W/ActivityManager(517): Force removing ActivityRecord{4178d2a8 u0 com.___.___/com.___.___.activities.PreviousActivity}: app died, no saved state
04-25 08:00:37.428: W/InputDispatcher(517): channel '41e3b688 com.___.___/com.___.___.activities.PreviousActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
04-25 08:00:37.428: E/InputDispatcher(517): channel '41e3b688 com.___.___/com.___.___.activities.PreviousActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-25 08:00:37.428: W/InputDispatcher(517): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '41e3b688 com.___.___/com.___.___.activities.PreviousActivity (server)'
04-25 08:00:37.428: I/WindowState(517): WIN DEATH: Window{41a48790 u0 com.___.___/com.___.___.activities.ActivityOther}
04-25 08:00:37.428: I/WindowState(517): WIN DEATH: Window{41e3b688 u0 com.___.___/com.___.___.activities.PreviousActivity}
```

If it helps, it seems to crash faster if I turn the screen on and off after going back to the MapFragment activity...

I know it has something to do with starting the activity twice, but I can't see anything anywhere that would cause this weird crash, plus, it didn't happen on v1... bleh.

Have tried google multiple times trying to figure it out too...

Also, if this helps, the Exception seems to occur in a separate thread at bk.run() as noted in the stacktrace, but my app continues to function on my device while its suspended in eclipse until I let that thread go and then the app actually crashes.

I've also confirmed that the crash occurs when I go to the activity with the map fragment twice, even if I never do anything with the map, or even call getMap() on the SupportMapFragment, so its definitely some kind of issue with the map fragment or with the loading in of google maps. Also crashes on rotate (as activity is recreated.)

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.  The real reason is lower down...

Comment: Yes, please post the whole trace. Off the cuff, this feels like a Maps V2 bug, but perhaps we will see something with the rest of the trace that may be useful.

Comment: edited, unfortunately the actual stacktrace is only what I originally posted... :( There was a few more lines I thought may be useful from the logcat though.

Comment: Looks to me like you've caught a Maps bug as CW says.

Comment: Really weird since the maps v2 examples seem to not have this crash... Either I'm doing something wrong somewhere (I'm following the example and api docs as much as possible) or there actually is a bug in Maps v2. I'm using ActionBarSherlock, that's probably the one difference between my app and the examples... but don't know why that would cause a problem... I created a SherlockMapFragment class as I've seen others do, but that didn't seem to change things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was caused by my app executing the following line when the app started up:

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CustomCookieManager());
```

Then, if that line had been executed previously, maps would crash after the second entry into the activity.

That explains why the stacktrace shows the crash occurring at addCookies. The app doesn't even use the Cookie Manager anymore anyway, so all I had to do was take out that line.

I knew it had to be something my app was doing different than the examples, and finally figured it out.

Don't know if that's still a bug in maps api v2 having to do with cookies? Probably not? My app may have been handling cookies wrong somehow. (Probably by not doing anything with the manager except setting it as default)... Anyway, now at least I can use them without a problem!